# android IntentService what can be wrong when intent is empty?

Tags: android, android-intent

hi
After creating intents for month now i suddenly
hit the wall when in my Notification PendingIntent, i did this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendFileService.class);
intent.putExtra("uuid", "123-456-34");
```

The SendFileService is an `IntentService`.

To my surprise in the `IntentService onHandleIntent` the `extras.getString("uuid");`

was null.

what can possible be the reason .
I even added an `action` to test but still the same.
Im clearly did something wrong or missing some knowledge about this.

Any ide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

> The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".